# Google Maps V2 Android with API KEY showing blank

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to add a map view to my app but the map shows a blank screen, I searched for this problem and I added every permission I need and the API key but still blank.
This is my code for the map

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:apiKey="-----------------------------------"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
```

This is the java code in onCreateView (I'm using fragments)

```
 mapview = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapview.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mapview.getMapAsync(this);
```

And

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    GoogleMap map = googleMap;
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getContext(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    GeoPoint location = user.getLocation();
    LatLng pos;
    if(location == null) pos = new LatLng(41.8919300, 12.5113300);
    else pos = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pos)
            .title("Ti trovi qui"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(pos,10f));
    mapview.onResume();

}
```

And this is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.diy.yourself">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<permission
    android:name="com.diy.yourself.permissions.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.diy.yourself.permissions.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name="com.diy.yourself.SignInActivity"
        android:label="Sign In"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.diy.yourself.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.diy.yourself.SignUpActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="-----------------------------------------"/>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

    <activity android:name="com.diy.yourself.ConditionsActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

The Google Maps for Android API is enabled and the key I used is the one auto-generated by Firebase that is working for other APIs, the debugger doesn't show any error.

Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using physical device or emulator . Check whether you have applied any restriction on android apps . Feel free to chat .

Answer (score 0):

you must add this meta to your manifest

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="----------------------------"/>
```

No need to add apiKey to xml. so remove this line from `MapView`

```
android:apiKey="-----------------------------------"
```

And add this lines in your fragment

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: Doesn't throw any error but map still showing blank 

Comment: Sorry for the late but I've paused my project and I completely forgot to answer this. No this didn't solved my problem. It throws an error on getMapAsync which is called on a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

and this code for definition

```
// Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: My map is inside a fragment, is not a fragment itself. getSupportFragmentManager gives me "cannot resolve method"